# populated hard disk partitioning/moving (a lot of operations)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I have a HHD which is actually a mess. I would like to organize it and exclude some partitions I don't want to use anymore.
Positioning the HD partitions beautifully require moving entire partition to another part of the disk, giving me this information:

> **Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot.**
>
> You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition
> /dev/sdb5.  Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the
> GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows
> system partition C:. You can learn how to repair the boot
> configuration in the GParted FAQ. http://gparted.org/faq.php
>
> Moving a partition might take a very long time to apply.

I'm currently running debian7 on a SSD /dev/sda, which is handling the boot. Is it safe to make all these operations? Is there any chance to lose data?
Thanks

current hard disk structure & desired hard disk structure at gparted: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6171737/screenshots/screenshot-window-2013-03-31-103706.jpg

Comment: Yes there's a chance. Make a backup first.  But as-is this question doesn't really fit this site.

Comment: I was sent here after posting it on stackoverflow :(
Where shall I ask?

Comment: backup the data then there is no risk. The message says you can make it boot after, even if there is a problem. But if there's a powercut you may be screwed if you haven't backed up. back it up then there's no risk. Posting because you're scared of a warning message is lame as hell.

Comment: I came here to learn more about the risks of this operation. The main threat is powercut? I don't have a spare 500gb hd, if I had I would never waste time doing this thing..

Comment: Whenever you mess with partitions there's always the possibility of data loss. Either backup first, or if you can't then assume the risk of data loss and proceed. There's nothing much to say besides this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Regarding the warning

If I understood correctly, you have installed the operating system on `/dev/sda`. Therefore, moving partitions on `/dev/sdb` will not cause your computer to fail to boot.

Even if it did, this would be easily fixable by booting from a Live CD and reinstalling GRUB.

#### Regarding data loss

There are three common scenarios that can cause massive data loss when moving partitions:

1. A faulty hard drive.
2. A system-wide crash.
3. Sudden power loss.

The latter two become a lot less likely if you boot from a Live CD (they *usually* don't crash) and connect your computer to a UPS.

The first scenario is a little more difficult to prevent. A little problem that would usually corrupt a single file could corrupt an entire partition.